# Can I change the verbose_name for a field inherited from the parent class in Django?

Tags: python, django

There is a parent class

```
class Category(models.Model)
    category = models.CharField('category', max_length=255, blank=True, help_text='Specified category')
```

Can I change the verbose_name for the category field in the descendant class? And also help_text?
Something like this:

```
class TableCategory(Category)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name__category = 'table category'
        help_text__category = 'Specified table category'

class ChairCategory(Category)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name__category = 'chair category'
        help_text__category = 'Specified chair category'
```

Comment: Did you run it and saw the result? If yours doesn't work then try to add verbose_name to your main CharfFeld like this `category = models.CharField('category', max_length=255, blank=True, verbose_name='category',help_text='Specified category')` then try to override `verbose_name`s again.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that in the `__init__` method:

```
class TableCategory(Category):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        field = self._meta.get_field('category')
        field.verbose_name = 'table category'
        ...
```